# Missing Dapr Side-Car in POD with NGINX in AKS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, dapr

I have a AKS cluster running in Azure and have deployed Dapr runtime into it along with a few other test service deployments that are annotated with dapr.io/enabled, dapr.io/id.

A Daprd side-car container instance co-locates within the same pod as each service so all is good there.

I then installed NGINX with the Dapr side-car annotations however I do not see a Daprd container instance co-located within the same pod as the NGINX container.

I followed [this article](https://carlos.mendible.com/2020/04/05/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-with-dapr/) to deploy NGINX with Dapr annotations applied through dapr-annotation.yaml file

[image]

Here are my workloads...

[image]

Here are my Services and ingresses...

[image]

Deployed Service1 has side-car...

[image]

Deployed Echo Service has side-car...

[image]

NGINX does not have a side-car but has annotations...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to changes to the Helm chart format to the following.

[image]

As a result of that change I now see the Darp side car on NGINX ingress controller as expected.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm glad that you found out the issue but please remember to not include images in your questions/answers apart from diagrams and rendered bugs. Here you can find more information on the reasoning behind it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @DawidKruk I was not aware of the policy, thanks for letting me know. Just to be clear, the two configuration settings are in conflict with the policy but the screen shots are ok?